# Provide option --define-variable to pkg-config from CMake / PkgConfig

Tags: windows, cmake, cygwin, build-process, pkg-config

In an attempt to port a Linux program on Windows (using cygwin and gcc), I am trying to properly find libraries that provide `pkg-config` files (in my case, the libraries are brought by Graphviz).

The straightforward method works on Linux:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(LIB_GRAPHVIZ libcdt libgvc libgraph)
```

On Windows, I manually installed Graphviz using the installer (cygwin path: `/cygdrive/c/graphviz`). In order to find the `pkg-config` files, I export the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable so that the `.pc` files are found prior configuring CMake:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/cygdrive/c/graphviz/pkgconfig
cmake $srcdir
```

Configuration works fine, however the `.pc` files do not have the appropriate prefix (which leads to invalid include and link directories):

```
$ pkg-config --variable=prefix libgraph
/c/graphviz-mingw/local.2.20.3
```

Regarding `pkg-config`, the solution is to invoke it with the `--define-variable` argument, for example here is how to get a valid `includedir`:

```
$ pkg-config --define-variable=prefix=/cygdrive/c/graphviz --variable=includedir libgraph
/cygdrive/c/graphviz/include/graphviz
```

My problem: how can I provide the `--define-variable` argument to `pkg-config` when it is invoked from within CMake?

`PkgConfig` defines `PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE` that points to the `pkg-config` program; I tried to append my option to this variable:

```
set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE "${PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE} --define-variable=/cygdrive/c/graphviz")
```

But `pkg_check_modules()` fails to detect my libraries. My understanding is that the call to `execute_process()` considers the content of `${PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE}` as an invalid program.

Any workaround I can use to address my problem?

---

Edit: actually, a simple workaround is to use different `.pc` files. But I am curious whether it is possible to solve the issue without having to alter these files.

Comment: I faced with the same issue, maybe you have found another solution then described workaround?

Comment: @CAMOBAP Not that I recall of, unfortunately; I checked the latest CMake documentation and it does not provide any means to do this. So the workaround is still the only solution, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your idea of overwriting `PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE`! This does indeed work for me if the parameter is separated by a semicolon, like this:

```
set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE "${PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE};--define-variable=/cygdrive/c/graphviz")
```

CMake will treat this as a list, and since `execute_process()` expects a list of command parameters, this works well (tested with CMake 3.17 under Linux).

Answer (score 1):

I think in [CMake 3.28](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.28/release/3.28.html#modules) and above, you can use the `DEFINE_VARIABLES` parameter of [`pkg_get_variable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.28/module/FindPkgConfig.html#command:pkg_get_variable).

Docstring: "*Specify key-value pairs to redefine variables affecting the variable retrieved with pkg-config.*"

Signature:

```
pkg_get_variable(<resultVar> <moduleName> <varName>
                 DEFINE_VARIABLES <key>=<value>...)
```